# Inner Join two table-Valued Parameters doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to 'inner join' two table values parameters but when i execute the query it takes for ever and i have to stop debug in ms sql server management studio 2008.

The query:

```
    @allClients [dbo].[ImportedClients] READONLY,
    @NewClients [dbo].[ImportedClients] READONLY

--Update Clients table in db with new clients

    UPDATE [dbo].[Clients]
        SET 

            Email = ISNULL(ct.Email, x.Email), 
            FirstName = ISNULL(ct.FirstName, x.FirstName), 
            LastName = ISNULL(ct.LastName, x.LastName), 
            Telephone = ISNULL(ct.Telephone, x.Telephone), 
            Cellphone = ISNULL(ct.Cellphone, x.Cellphone), 



        FROM @NewClients ct
        inner join @allClients x 
        ON (x.Email = ct.Email)     

        WHERE ct.Status > -1
```

What i am trying to do is: Update all the clients information for rows that exist in both @NewClients and @allClients so i used inner join. 
Is it possible to JOIN two  table-Valued Parameters?
This query doesn't (query doesn't complete without an error) work even with a few rows.

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried a `SELECT * FROM @NewClients ct inner join @allClients x ON (x.Email = ct.Email) WHERE ct.Status > -1` ?

Comment: You are missing any join onto `[dbo].[Clients]` so you will end up with all rows being updated with arbitrary values.

Comment: How are you supposed to link the records from your table valued parameters with the records on the `[dbo].[Clients]` table?, you are not linking them

Comment: @Nathan koop- yes, actually it did work with select, but it returns both '@NewClients' and '@allClients' columns in one row (so i have two emails, FirstName, etc columns) . but the update doesn't work.

Comment: @Lamak i believe you are right, need to link dbo.Clients.. umm

Comment: As @MartinSmith said, you are updating your table with arbitrary values, and if you already tried your query, you most likely changed the values of the `[dbo].[Clients]` table

Comment: How can i fix the query to link  with dbo.Clients if i need the Inner join between the tables..?

Comment: Well, you should tell us how those table valued parameters are joined with the clients table. Is there a field to join on?, something?

Comment: Then what is the point on updating the `Email` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference `[dbo].[Clients]` in the `FROM` clause of your SQL.

Something like this:

```
@allClients [dbo].[ImportedClients] READONLY,
@NewClients [dbo].[ImportedClients] READONLY

--Update Clients table in db with new clients

UPDATE [dbo].[Clients]
SET 
    Email = ISNULL(ct.Email, x.Email), 
    FirstName = ISNULL(ct.FirstName, x.FirstName), 
    LastName = ISNULL(ct.LastName, x.LastName), 
    Telephone = ISNULL(ct.Telephone, x.Telephone), 
    Cellphone = ISNULL(ct.Cellphone, x.Cellphone), 

FROM [dbo].[Clients] c
    INNER JOIN @NewClients ct ON (c.Email = ct.Email)     
    INNER JOIN @allClients x  ON (x.Email = ct.Email)     
WHERE ct.Status > -1
```